# PyQt5: Remove background color in in a QrCode

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

this is a QrCode generator in python via `PyQt5` and the module `qrcode` I have a widget with its own color;

I want to remove the WHITE COLOR to **TRANSPARENT** or **NO COLOR**

```py
# importing libraries
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import qrcode
import sys

class Image(qrcode.image.base.BaseImage):
    def __init__(self, border, width, box_size):
        self.border = border
        self.width = width
        self.box_size = box_size
        size = (width + border * 2) * box_size
        self._image = QImage(size, size, QImage.Format_RGB16)

        # initial image as white
        self._image.fill(Qt.white)

    def pixmap(self):
        return QPixmap.fromImage(self._image)

    def drawrect(self, row, col):
        painter = QPainter(self._image)
        painter.fillRect(
            (col + self.border) * self.box_size,
            (row + self.border) * self.box_size,
            self.box_size, self.box_size,
            QtCore.Qt.black)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 300, 300)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.edit.returnPressed.connect(self.handleTextEntered)
        self.edit.setFont(QFont('Times', 9))
        self.edit.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.edit)
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def handleTextEntered(self):
        text = self.edit.text()
        qr_image = qrcode.make(text, image_factory = Image).pixmap()
        self.label.setPixmap(qr_image)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

#### I tried this, but to no avail:

```py
self._image.fill(Qt.transparent)
```

```py
self._image.fill(Qt.'rgba(122, 45, 78, 1)')
```

```py
self._image.fill(None)
```

```py
self._image.fill('')
```

```py
self._image.fill()
```

```py
# self._image.fill() # to remove the
```

these attempts didn't work,...Any idea

Comment: The RGB16 format doesn't support transparency. Is that format required by the inherited class? Do you *actually* need a `QImage` at all?

Comment: Is there a way to get QrCode without `QImage` ?, Please, I will appreaciate any example sir

Comment: I don't have that module, so you have to answer what I asked. If you don't know that, you need study the documentation.

Comment: @musicamante Yes sir, I actually need `QImage` because i use it to save QrCodes images as png files (but I am ready to ignore savings images, just to have a transparent qrcode

Comment: that's irrelevant: QPixmap can also be saved, just like QImage.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an image format that does *not* support transparency:

```
self._image = QImage(size, size, QImage.Format_RGB16)
```

As the documentation [explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum):

> The image is stored using a 16-bit RGB format (5-6-5).

This means that it's a standard (and very limited) [3-components color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monochrome_and_RGB_color_formats#16-bit_RGB) where channels are only *red* (5 bits, 32 levels), *green* (6 bits, 64 levels) and *blue* (5 bits, 32 levels again), and clearly no alpha channel.

Since the requirement is only to be able to show and save the image, there's no need to use QImage and specify the format, and QPixmap is certainly more easier and appropriate, especially considering that it natively supports transparency.

```
class Image(qrcode.image.base.BaseImage):
    def __init__(self, border, width, box_size):
        self.border = border
        self.width = width
        self.box_size = box_size
        size = (width + border * 2) * box_size
        self._image = QPixmap(size, size)
        self._image.fill(Qt.transparent)

    def pixmap(self):
        return self._image

    def drawrect(self, row, col):
        painter = QPainter(self._image)
        painter.fillRect(
            (col + self.border) * self.box_size,
            (row + self.border) * self.box_size,
            self.box_size, self.box_size,
            QtCore.Qt.black)
```